# Sessions in Symfony2 Test

Tags: php, symfony, session, functional-testing

I need to get session_id in these view as it was stored in the database. I use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client.

When I try something like this:

`$cookies = $client->getCookieJar()->all(self::BASE_URL.$ltiLoginUrl);
 foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
     var_dump($cookie);
 }`

I get such output:

```
class Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie#11238 (8) {
  protected $name =>
  string(10) "MOCKSESSID"
  protected $value =>
  string(64) "9d2b2a5b307c3e330dc4407a6e0a109f57008128614a85056479731ee5284157"
  protected $expires =>
  int(0)
  protected $path =>
  string(1) "/"
  protected $domain =>
  string(9) "localhost"
  protected $secure =>
  bool(false)
  protected $httponly =>
  bool(false)
  protected $rawValue =>
  string(64) "9d2b2a5b307c3e330dc4407a6e0a109f57008128614a85056479731ee5284157"
}
```

My question is how to get real session id in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the use case for re-using an existing session? It think what you're looking for is how to simulate authentication: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/simulating_authentication.html

Comment: No, I understand that it looks weird, but it depends on this project strange feature.

Comment: Okay, then the answer is you can't because PHPUnit is executed via CLI and it doesn't share runtime variables with the Apache handler :-) Or do you have another definition of the session id? You might store sessions in your database?

Comment: @Rvanlaak , thank you for your answer.